# how to test sorting using c# and visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, selenium-webdriver

I have a table that contains a column with employee names. I have to test weather the employee name sorted out alphabetically using automation.
I am new to C# and visual studio with previous knowledge of JAVA.My question is firstly how do we get all employee names from column using C# and store it in a list and
than test weather the employee names are present in alphabetical order or not.Any pseudo code or help will be highly appreciated.

xpath: //*[@id='EMPLOYEE_ROW_0'] for employee 1,//*[@id='EMPLOYEE_ROW_1'] for employee 2 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Just InnerText() the row and change the string to only include what you want to fill your list.